# Jquery Animate on IE makes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I write these code and make it work in IE&chrome&firefox,It works well in chrome and firefox but wrong in IE. somebody tells me why,thanks!

these codes makes a animation when I push start button, I hope it stop when I push stop button,but when I push stop, the alert shows so much times.

ok,this is my code. becareful about your browser, maybe it will crash when the animation is playing.

forgive me about my poor english

```
<html style = "overflow:hidden">
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
var DIV ;
var CONTENT ;
var move = false;
$(function(){
    DIV = $('<img src="7.png"></img>');
    CONTENT = $('#content');
});
function startAnimation(){
    $('#content').empty();
    var div = $('<img src="7.png"></img>');
    div.appendTo('#content');

    var w_w=$(document).width();
    var d_w=div.width();
    var l=w_w/2 - d_w/2; 

    div.css("position","absolute");
    div.css("top",$(document).height()+div.height());
    div.css("left",l);

    if(!move){
        div.animate({top:-div.height(),left:l},1000,function(){
            alert('ok');
            return;
        });
    }else{
        div.animate({top:-div.height(),left:l},1000,function(){
        //setTimeout(function(){
            startAnimation.call(window);
            return;
        });
    }
}
function start(){
    if(!move){
        move = true;
        startAnimation();
    }
}
function stop(){
    move = false;
}
</script>
<body  style = "overflow:hidden">
<button onclick="start();">start</button>
<button onclick="stop();">stop</button>
<div id='content' sytle="width:1000px;height:700px;overflow:hidden">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Internet Explorer versions does ignore css values; without `px` at the end of it.

`top:200` returns error but `top:200px` works fine on ie.

Try this:

```
if(!move){
   div.animate({'top':-div.height()+'px','left':l + 'px'},1000,function(){//here
        alert('ok');
        return;
   });
}else{
   div.animate({'top':-div.height()+'px','left':l + 'px'},1000,function(){//+'px'
        startAnimation.call(window);
        return;
   });
}
```

Comment: I have tried add the 'px',but it doesn't work. the alert shows not only one time, I don't understand

Comment: can you show your example? or you can show us on jsFiddle too so we can solve this fast. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: this example with 'px' added is working on my ie 7 8 9, can you be more spesefic on your problem please? http://jsbin.com/ivemug/2/edit

Comment: thank you , I know it's working ,the animation worked, but can you tell me what happened when you push the 'stop' button? how many times it alerted? it should alert once but not.maybe you could create a html file on your pc and paste the code into the file,then run it and try to push stop.